# Where get data to compare cache algorithms

Tags: caching, data-generation, data-collection

I wan`t to compare cache algorithms like LRU, SLRU, LFU etc on real data.

That`s why I need some method to generate real-like data to compare cache algorithms or to get this data from some application.

Answer (score 1):

I think [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html), one of the tools in the valgrind suite, might be what you're looking for.  I haven't used it myself, but from a glance at that page, it produces an output file `cachegrind.out.<pid>` with human-readable information about cache accesses.  Not sure if it will be as detailed as you need (maybe it's just a summary), but probably worth a look.

Comment: It's not exactly what I've trying to find, but it`s better than nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest you one of faker library depending on the programming language.

- [Ruby](https://github.com/stympy/faker)
- [PHP](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)
- [Python](https://github.com/joke2k/faker)
- [Javascript](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/)
- [JAVA](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker)
- [C#](https://github.com/slashdotdash/faker-cs)

Comment: Nice library, but can you describe more how to use this library to generate data according to my question(in any language you like)?

Comment: what are the generate data format do you expect? Json?

Comment: Problem not in format, problem in data what this library return. This library return some random data, but I need a tool what can write in separate file each memory adress or memory page, or memory block(like in ext4) what need OS to run calculator for example. Maybe I need specify this in question.